# jquery detect if user clicked on input - if not do something

Tags: jquery

I have a button, when clicking on it a login is showing up. I would like that if the input wasn't clicked after (let's say) 10 seconds, the `.login` will hide and the button will show up again.

Markup:

```
<button>login</button>

<div class="login" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function(){
            $('.login').fadeIn();
        });        
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxohzxt9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

```js
$(function(){
    var timer;
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function(){
            $('.login').fadeIn();
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.login').fadeOut(function() {
                    $('button').fadeIn();
                });
            }, 2000); // 2 seconds for demo
        });        
    });
    
    $('input[type="text"]').on('focus',function() {
       clearTimeout(timer); 
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>login</button>

<div class="login" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</div>
```

Comment: This uses global variable.  Something you want to avoid.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Where is the global variable?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 If you are talking about `timer` then notice the surrounding function. Not global.

Comment: so if you put it outside of the dom ready scope, its not global?  still seems like it woudl be considered global

Comment: If it were outside of the function it would be global; but it isn't. If you try to access the variable outside of the above code it will be undefined. - edit: perhaps you missed this on the second line... `var timer;`

Answer (score 0):

do sth like this (modify as needed):

$(function(){

```
var clickedOnInput = false;
$('.login').on('mousedown', 'input', function(){
    clickedOnInput = true;
});
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('.login').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
           if (!clickedOnInput) 
           {
            //fadeback to other panel 

           }
           clickedOnInput = false; // reset the variable
        }, 10000)
    });        
});
```

});